# How to clear animation in right way

Tags: android, animation

I am confused with a problem:

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 200, 0);
animation.setDuration(800);
animation.setFillAfter(true);

btnView.startAnimation(animation);
btnView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I run this code work right but when I add the below code:

```
btnView.clearAnimation();
```

The animation can't show, how to clear animation after this?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You want to show your animation or clear it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to clear the animations for the view once the animations i finished

you have to override Animation Listener of view and then clear the animation

if you want your view to move back to intial postion just setFillafter(false);

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO set params of the view to required position

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

To clear animation after it is finished set  [setFillAfter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29) to false.

Answer (score 0):

use this way:

```
// start animation
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, 100 , 0, 100);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setFillAfter( true );
view.startAnimation(anim);

// end animation or cancel that
view.getAnimation().cancel();
view.clearAnimation();
```

**cancel()**

Cancel the animation. Canceling an animation invokes the animation
listener, if set, to notify the end of the animation.
If you cancel an animation manually, you must call reset()
before starting the animation again.

**clearAnimation()**

Cancels any animations for this view.